# Can I deploy node.js on Azure node app server by just copying files?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Azure websites now has the option to set up a node.js server. The Microsoft documentation on deployment has some rather complicated steps involving PowerShell scripts.

Can I deploy my app by just copying everything including the node modules in my current folder over, and just leaving the following files on the server alone:

1. web.config
2. iisnode.yml
3. azuredeploy.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can. What makes up your Azure Web App is the set of files that end up in your wwwroot folder, regardless of how they end up there: git deployment, FTP, drag and drop from Kudu Console, ...

For Node, minimally you're going to need `web.config`, `iisnode.yml` and your `server.js`. You do *not* need `azuredeploy.json`, which is an ARM template used client side that doesn't need to be deployed to the server.

Comment: This is true for Windows host, but if your hosting the Node app on linux you don't need the web.config and iisnode.yml files.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment cannot work by simply copying the file. you may be able to copy the files but the node server would not run automatically. Since this are not a VM you cannot connect remotely and run the start node server command. But there are various options available if you do not want to use powershell.

1) You can deploy to azure websites/ web app from your local git commandline if the code is in local git repository using the git remote command. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-local-git

2) You can use azure CLI ( command line interface) and deploy the code from git to azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started

3) If you use visual studio IDE then you can install the nodejs tools for Visual studio and it gives you options to publish to your azure subscription.

4) You can publish code via ftp to the azure app service endpoint and then use the visual studio online  kudu console and run the server.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2015/12/01/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-site-into-azure-web-app-to-create-a-website/

Comment: The creation of the Azure website already got the node.js server running.  The Hello World sample in the server.js works.  Can't I just replace server.js and add my other files?

Comment: yes you can. you may have to restart the server once you are done with the changes. it is always a better practice to have standard publishing/ deployment process.

Comment: I tried, and it didn't work. The only two files replaced were server.js and package.json. The item I can see materially different in package.json is the "script" key. Microsoft's says "node server". Mine says "node server.js".